# Multiple XML file parsing with pagination in PHP

Tags: php, xml, pagination

I have a folder on the server with almost 9,000 small XML files (NewsML) with varying numbers of news items in each - but usually from 1 - 10 items in each file.

I need to retrieve the items via PHP and then paginate the results.
So there would be ten items per page and end up with hundreds of paginated pages of the results.

I can retrieve the multiple file names no problem using `scandir` but am having a hard time figuring out how I would return the results and paginate (in a performance friendly way as well).

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php & http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.paginator.simple.html might be helpful...

Comment: Performance friendly != Reading 9000 files everytime for your pagination, database sounds great

Answer (score 1):

Better import them to your database, using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and start paginating from there.
This makes retrieval easy in PHP.